# Get preferred height of div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I use a chrome extension to collapse certain divisions on webpages. And ti all works pretty well. I made it so that it is has a height of 50px, and when you hover over it it becomes the height it usually is. In short this is what my code does:

- Check the height of a div -> checkedHeight
- Apply CSS rule: max-height: 50px
- Apply CSS rule on Hover: max-height: checkedHeight

This works like a charm. But!!! When the div loads extra content, it becomes longer. Is there anyway i could set max-height to be the preferred height of an element? I know i could just not use max-height, but i want to use css3 transitions to make the div expand gradually.

Comment: What about max-height: auto?

Answer (score 1):

Use [element.scrollHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.scrollHeight)

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Uhk4M/)

```
<script>
    function collapse(target) {
        target.style.maxHeight = '50px';
    }
    function expand(target) {
        target.style.maxHeight = target.scrollHeight + 'px';
    }
</script>

<style>
    #test {
        max-height: 50px;
        background:lightgray;
        overflow: hidden;

        -moz-transition: 1s;
        -ms-transition: 1s;
        -o-transition: 1s;
        -webkit-transition: 1s;
        transition: 1s;
    }
</style>

<div id="test" onmouseover="expand(this)" onmouseout="collapse(this)">
    text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>
    text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>
    text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>
</div>
```

Comment: Trying to do something similar but `scrollHeight` is always equal to `maxHeight`.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just set `max-height: none` when hovering?

Comment: I could. But there would be no transition. Max-height A to B will make a div transition from it's small height to big height. From A to None will not transition, it would just be there all of a sudden.

Comment: what about setting max-height to a high number like 999px when hovering?

Comment: I tried that. It works in the sens that it still animates and shows everything. But there is a major downside. If you would want to be save, and would for instance take 10000 as rhe max height, and your div would be only 500px high, you would speed up the transition 20 times, which means you can not really see the transition

Comment: Then adjust the transition speed to account for the extra length maybe?

Comment: That is a nice idea. Except that it would run too long. An animation could run for 20 seconds that way. Which would mean that if i would collapse it again by mouse out, it would take about 20 seconds before you see the desired effect?

Comment: Seems to work fine on the fiddle I added. The animation is stopped as soon as you mouse out, it does not wait until completion.

Comment: Thats true. But if your mouse would be hovering the dov for 20 seconds it would have completed the animation. Most times my users would be hovering for about 30 seconds

Comment: Sorry I don't follow you I must be missing part of what the desired effect is.